# DiscordJS Bot Broken

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have used Discord.js before and everything has been fine. For some reason lately Discord.JS has been buggy and has problems. In this code I try making a simple on message event command for "ping", also have tried to set the presence. Nothing happens for any of it. Once the bot is online it does print out that the bot im using is online "Bot#9796" and it does actually turn online + correct token. I'm unsure why the command doesn't work and why it doesnt print out all messages and also the status. If anyone knows how to fix all of this being broken please let me know! Thanks.

Here is the code

```
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    ],
});


client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
  client.user.setPresence({
    activity: {
      name: 'with Discord.js'
    },
    status: 'online'
  });
});

client.on('message', message => {
  console.log(message.content);
  if (message.content === 'ping') {
    message.channel.send('pong');
  }
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Answer (score 2):

The `message` event has been renamed to `messageCreate` in v14, try renaming the event.